# Write data to disk in Python as a background process

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing

I have a program in Python that basically does the following:

```
for j in xrange(200):
    # 1) Compute a bunch of data
    # 2) Write data to disk
```

1) takes about 2-5 minutes
2) takes about ~1 minute

Note that there is too much data to keep in memory.

Ideally what I would like to do is write the data to disk in a way that avoids idling the CPU. Is this possible in Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try [using multiple processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def compute(j):
    # compute a bunch of data
    return data

def write(data):
    # write data to disk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for j in xrange(200):
        pool.apply_async(compute, args=(j, ), callback=write)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

`pool = mp.Pool()` will create a pool of worker processes. By default, the number of workers equals the number of CPU cores your machine has.

Each [pool.apply_async](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) call queues a task to be run by a worker in the pool of worker processes. When a worker is available, it runs `compute(j)`. When the worker returns a value, `data`, a thread in the main process runs the callback function `write(data)`, with `data` being the data returned by the worker.

Some caveats:

- The data has to be picklable, since it is being communicated from the
  worker process back to the main process via a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).
- There is no guarantee that the order in which the workers complete
  tasks is the same as the order in which the tasks were sent to the
  pool. So the order in which the data is written to disk may not
  correspond to `j` ranging from 0 to 199. One way around this problem
  would be to write the data to a sqlite (or other kind of) database
  with `j` as one of the fields of data. Then, when you wish to read
  the data in order, you could `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY j`.
- Using multiple processes will increase the amount of memory required
  as data is generated by the worker processes and data waiting to be written to disk accumulates in the Queue. You
  might be able to reduce the amount of memory required by using NumPy
  arrays. If that is not possible, then you might have to reduce the
  number of processes:

  ```
  pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
  ```

  That will create one worker process (to run `compute`), leaving the
  main process to run `write`. Since `compute` takes longer than
  `write`, the Queue won't get backed up with more than one chunk of
  data to be written to disk. However, you would still need enough memory
  to compute on one chunk of data while writing a different chunk of
  data to disk.

  If you do not have enough memory to do both simultaneously, then you have no choice -- your original code, which runs `compute` and `write` sequentially, is the only way.

Comment: Why use processes and the write to a file is just IO and don't affect GIL?

Comment: 2-5 minutes is being spent on computation, compared to only 1 minute of IO. If the machine has multiple cores, you could speed up the computation by spreading the work among the cores.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is very helpful. I'm dealing with NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something such as `Queue.Queue` (the module is here: [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)) and `threading.Thread` (or `threading.start_new_thread` if you just want a function), the module is here: [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) - As a file write is not CPU intensive and use more IO. (and the GIL doesn't affect it).

Answer (score 2):

Simple way would be to use just threading and the queue. On the other hand, if the computing part does not depend on global state, and you have machine with multiple CPU cores, more efficient way would be to use [process pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def compute_data(x):
    return some_calculation_with(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4) # let's say you have quad-core, so start 4 workers

    with open("output_file","w") as outfile:
        for calculation_result in pool.imap(compute_data, range(200)):
        # pool.imap returns results as they come from process pool    
            outfile.write(calculation_result)
```